# Using google translate api in userscript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am making a userscript for facebook that would help translate text using Google Translate Api. Script is  injecting html and css content successfully into facebook.

Problem is with Google Translate Api. I am injecting a script tag

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type="text/javascript";
s.src='https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyD24A-czAdTj8pPc5ugo0bYiPRx8Rc2pXo';
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

First this script is loading the url 2 or 3 times.

To actually use the Language Api I am injecting another script tag

```
var ldfun = document.createElement('script');
ldfun.setAttribute('type', 'application/javascript');
ldfun.textContent= "google.load('language','1');";
document.body.appendChild(ldfun);
```

this script is not running and sometimes it runs then the page naviages away.

Help please

Comment: I assume you are talking about Greasemonkey user script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the script is not running in iFrames and then use a delay to ensure the library JS is loaded (Otherwise, the browser will run those 2 `script`s asynchronously.)

Something like this:

```
if (window.top != window.self)  //-- Don't run on frames or iframes
    return;

function addJS_Node (text, s_URL)
{
    var scriptNode                      = document.createElement ('script');
    scriptNode.type                     = "text/javascript";

    if (text)  scriptNode.textContent   = text;
    if (s_URL) scriptNode.src           = s_URL;

    //--- document.head is best.  Use document.body only on poor target pages.
    document.head.appendChild (scriptNode);
}

//--- Load Google-Translate, JS API.
addJS_Node (null, 'https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyD24A-czAdTj8pPc5ugo0bYiPRx8Rc2pXo');

//--- Initialize Google-Translate after a delay to make sure it has loaded.
setTimeout (function() {
    addJS_Node ("google.load('language','1');", null);
    },
    1500
);
```

Comment: That worked but now when the google.load executes the page actually navigates to that page. How to stop it from navigating?

Comment: I don't know, I'm unable to replicate the problem yet.   You might have better luck using Ajax calls to the translator tools.  There's less overhead and delay with loading that clunky library every time too.